Convert UK to German driving license document requirement
I wanted to know what documents I need to provide when I go for the appointment to convert my UK driving license to a German one in Berlin.

What has your research on this topic so far revealed?


I wanted to know what documents I need to provide when i go for the appointment to convert my UK license to a German one in Berlin.

Below is a quick and dirty translation from the link below.
The striked out portions are not relevant for the United Kingdom.
If you have not made an appointment yet, the page offers you the opportunity to select where you would like to do this and then passes you on to search for a free time slot (good luck with that ...)


Required documents

Identity card or passport
1 photograph (current biometric photo)
Details of the driving school and the test center (necessary for third countries and if applicable, Appendix 11 with test)

Name of the owner and address of the driving school as well as the name and address of the test center; once the test approval has been received, it is no longer possible to change the test center.


Presentation of the valid foreign driver's license and a copy of the driver's license

The foreign driver's license must still be valid at the time the German driver's license is applied for and must be in the original.
International driver's licenses are not converted; a valid national driver's license is always required.


Translation of the foreign driver's license if necessary

A translation is always required if the driver's license is not issued in German or English.
In case of doubt, the driver's license authority decides whether a translation of the foreign driver's license is required.
The translation will then be requested when the application is processed.


Proof of date of arrival in the Federal Republic and main place of residence (e.g. by means of registration certificate)
Proof of first aid training (third country)

Only required when converting a driving license from a third country


Eye test (for car and motorcycle driving license, classes A and B)

Third countries: An eye test is always required when converting a car or motorcycle class.
Countries in Annex 11: An eye test is generally not required unless it is stated in a footnote in the list of countries





Sources:

Fahrerlaubnis - Umschreibung einer ausländischen Fahrerlaubnis aus einem Nicht-EU/EWR-Land (Drittstaat/Anlage 11) - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de (German only)

Staaten der Anlage 11 FeV

United Kingdom

Class(es): all
The authority responsible under state law may require the applicant to undergo an eyesight test when issuing a driving license.
theoretical examination: no
practical examination: no







